# How to not apply style to input element that is invalid for the first time

Tags: css

I'm applying the `border-color` red to the input element on invalid and not disabled like in below snippet,

```
input:invalid:not(:disabled){
    border-color: $red_1;
    color: $text_gray;
}
```

But the above will add the `border-color` to red stating invalid even without user entering in the input field.

How do I overcome this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve this question and relate it to a more recent one with accepted answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675519/12718900

> You can use :placeholder-shown selector for empty state. There is :blank selector for input elements, but it is currently experimental.

[@Ahmet Zeybek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5061290/ahmet-zeybek)

Here you can see documentation about these pseudo-classes:

- `:blank`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank
- `:placeholder-shown`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown

Today, what about compatibility?

- `:blank` = 0%: https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ablank
- `:placeholder-shown` = 97.23% and 94.89% on non-`type="text"`: https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Aplaceholder-shown