# Why input:invalid is used as default instead of main input style?

Tags: html, css, validation

I have refered some posts and this stackoverflow link too : [Set input as invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128882/set-input-as-invalid) but didnt help much.

What I am trying to achieve is a normal styles input, 
when a user focuses the input we have border color changed. 
When we have a valid value in it we style it with input:valid 
else 
we style it with input:invalid.

I have almost achieved this however the input:invalid style is used as default. I want to have the border / background transparent initially.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 60px;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input:focus,
input:hover {
  border-bottom-color: dodgerblue;
}

input:invalid {
  border-bottom-color: red;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

input:valid {
  border-bottom-color: green;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

input:valid+.icon:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f599";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
}

input:invalid+.icon:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f119";
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <input type="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+" title="enter your email" placeholder="enter your email" required>
  <span class="icon">
        
      </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:placeholder-shown` selector for empty state. There is `:blank` selector for `input` elements, but it is currently experimental.

```css
body{
  height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  align-items:center;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 60px;
}
div{
  display:grid;
  position:relative;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

input:focus,input:hover{
  border-bottom-color:dodgerblue;
}
input:invalid{
  border-bottom-color:red;
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
input:valid{
  border-bottom-color:green;
  background:green;
  color:white;
}
input:valid + .icon:after{
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   content:"\f599";
  color:white;
  font-weight:900;
}
input:invalid + .icon:after{
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content:"\f119";
  font-weight:900;
  color:white;
}
.icon{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  height:35px;
  width:35px;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
}
input{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
  height:35px; 
  padding:10px;
  padding-right:35px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition:all 500ms linear;
}
input:placeholder-shown {
  border-bottom-color:pink;
  background:pink;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <input
    type="email" 
    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+"
    title="enter your email"
    placeholder="enter your email"
    required>
  <span class="icon">

  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well, unless you don't want to put a placeholder in the input field. But in this case you can just add the attribute with an empty value, i.e. `placeholder=""` and it will still work even though there's no actual placeholder value. Using `:blank` might be nicer, but it's still not supported by any browsers at date of writing.